# How to completely remove head and tail white spaces or punctuation characters?

Tags: r, regex

I have `string_a`, such that

```
string_a <- " ,A thing, something, .   ."
```

Using `regex`, how can I just retain `"A thing, something"`?

I have tried the following and got such output:

```
sub("[[:punct:]]$|^[[:punct:]]","", trimws(string_a))
[1] "A thing, something, .   ."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match one or more punctuation characters including spaces (`[[:punct:] ] +`) from the start (`^`) or `|` those characters until the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("^[[:punct:] ]+|[[:punct:] ]+$", "", string_a)
#[1] "A thing, something"
```

Note: `sub` will replace only a single instance

Or as @Cath mentioned `[[:punct:] ]` can be replaced with `\\W`

Comment: probably you can use `\\W` instead of `[[:punct:] ]`

Comment: As usual, thanks for saving the day again! Great detail. 
p/s:`\\W` works well too.